# '?' in redirect shows 404 in Flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I have setted up a payment service on my flask web app so when the payment is successfully processed it redirects to a given url when I reach the url it shows `error code 404` but if I remove the "?" it works fine

**THE URL IT REDIRECTS TO**

[image]

**THE FLASK CODE**

```
@app.route("/account/billing/verified/<pid>")
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

```
@app.route("/account/billing/verified/?payment_id=<pid>")
```

Comment: Try this: /account/billing/verified?payment_id=<pid>

Comment: Still no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to use the `payment_id` as a `GET` parameter, therefore you can access it through `request.args`:

```
@app.route("/account/billing/verified", methods=['GET'])
```

Then you can access the `payment_id` the following way:

```
payment_id = request.args.get('payment_id', None)
```

If the parameter is not present in the url, it will fallback to `None`.